# Angular - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'licence_number')

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 I have this code:

And your JSON is invalid. It should be as below:

```
{
  "message": "Employee Detail.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "employee": {
      "id": 8,
      "first_name": "JONAH",
      "last_name": "YAKUBU",
      "other_name": "STANLEY",
      "licences": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "licence_number": "dsdsdsd"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

interface:

```
export class EmployeeResponse {
  results!: { employee: IEmployee };
}

export interface IEmployee {
  id?: number;
  first_name: string;
  other_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  licence_number?: string;
  licences?: ILicence[];
}

export interface ILicence {
  id: number;
  licence_number: string;
  dl_classification_id: number;
  licenceclass?: {id:number,class_name:string};
}
```

service:

```
  getEmployeeById(id: number): Observable<EmployeeResponse> {
    return this.http.get('/assets/data.json').pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        if (!response) return response;

        if (!response.results) return response;

        if (!response.results.employee) return response;

        let employee: IEmployee = {
          ...response.results.employee,
          licence_number:
            response.results.employee.licences &&
            response.results.employee.licences[0].licence_number
        };

        response.results.employee = employee;

        return response;
      })
    );
  }
```

component:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  profileInfoForm!: FormGroup;
  licenceInfoForm!: FormGroup;

  profileTemplate: boolean = true;
  licenceTemplate: boolean = false;

  isLoading = false;
  employee: IEmployee;
  _id = 1;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    //this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.updateEmployee();
    this.updateLicence();
    this.loadEmployeeById();
  }

  profileFunction() {
    this.profileTemplate = true;
    this.licenceTemplate = false;
  }

  licenceFunction() {
    this.profileTemplate = false;
    this.licenceTemplate = true;
  }

  updateEmployee() {
    this.profileInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      first_name: [
        '', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]
      ],
      other_name: ['', [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      last_name: [
        '', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]
      ]
    });
  }

  updateLicence() {
    this.licenceInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      licence_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]]
    });
  }

  get fp() {
    return this.profileInfoForm.controls;
  }
  get fl() {
    return this.licenceInfoForm.controls;
  }

  profileValidate() {
    if (!this.profileInfoForm.valid) {
      this.profileInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
  }

  licenceValidate() {
    if (!this.licenceInfoForm.valid) {
      this.licenceInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
      return;
    }
  }

  loadEmployeeById() {
    this.employeeService
      .getEmployeeById(this._id)
      .subscribe((data: EmployeeResponse) => {
        console.log(data.results.employee)
        this.employee = data.results.employee;
        this.profileInfoForm.patchValue({
          first_name: this.employee.first_name,
          other_name: this.employee.other_name,
          last_name: this.employee.last_name
        });
        this.licenceInfoForm.patchValue({
          licence_number: this.employee.licence_number
        });
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="sticky-top mb-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Click to Edit</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="external-events">
          <button (click)="profileFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Profile</button>
          <button (click)="licenceFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Licence</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-header">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9" *ngIf="employee != undefined">
  <div *ngIf="profileTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form [formGroup]="profileInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitProfile()">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first_name">First Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.touched && fp.first_name.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('required')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      First Name is required!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('minlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      First Name cannot be less than 2 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('maxlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      First Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="other_name">Middle Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="other_name" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control" required/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="fp.other_name.touched && fp.other_name.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="fp.other_name.hasError('maxlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Middle Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="last_name">Last Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" required/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.touched && fp.last_name.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('required')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Last Name is required!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('minlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Last Name cannot be less than 2 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('maxlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Last Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="profileValidate()">
                    <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="licenceTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">
    <form [formGroup]="licenceInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitLicence()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="licence_number">Licence Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="licence_number" placeholder="Licence Number" class="form-control" required/>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.touched && fl.licence_number.invalid">
            <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.hasError('required')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Licence Number is required!
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.hasError('minlength')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Licence Number cannot be less than 2 characters!
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.hasError('maxlength')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Licence Number cannot be more than 50 characters!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="licenceValidate()">
                    <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Initially, everything was working fine but suddenly, I got this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'licence_number')

which is coming from the service.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'licence_number')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let employee: IEmployee = {
    ...response.results.employee,
    licence_number:
                 (response.results.employee.licences &&
                  response.results.employee.licences[0] &&
                  response.results.employee.licences[0].licence_number ) 
                  ? response.results.employee.licences[0].licence_number : '';
```

Try to check better if the field is there and if not then provide an empty string `''`

Here is a simple example why your checks are not enough.

```
const c = {d: []}
console.log(c.d);   // -> prints []
console.log(c.d[0]); // -> prints undefined
```

You can also understand that is important to always patch the value with something. So if in the end the value you try to patch is `undefined`, it will fail. In that case you must first check and if `undefined` then patch it with an empty string `''`.

Answer (score 1):

I think or you read the wrong JSON or enter in one of this case...

```
if (!response) return response;

        if (!response.results) return response;

        if (!response.results.employee) return response;
```

Try to change this code into this

```
if (!response) return response;

        if (!response['results']) return response;

        if (!response['results']['employee']) return response;
```

Comment: can you print your response of this code?

Answer (score 1):

if you are checking like `ngIf="someArray[0]?`

then you should initialize your array on your component like this: `someArray: any[] = []`

if you just declare `someArray: any[]` it will give the error